# How do I get each "pais" value from $request in Symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, request

I've a HTML select in my form that has multiple option enabled so I can choose one or more. When I send the form through a Ajax call I can see this under "Headers" in Chrome dev tools (see image below):

```
paises[pais]:4
paises[pais]:5
paises[pais]:7
paises[pais]:8
paises[_token]:JEb4FuPxmptLLZ1Y_qTjWt09wKDqJwFeg2ug-EPD88Q
paises[idToUpdate]:6
```

[image]

And if I go through "view source" in the Chrome Dev Tools I can see this query string:

```
paises%5Bpais%5D=4&paises%5Bpais%5D=5&paises%5Bpais%5D=7&paises%5Bpais%5D=8&paises%5B_token%5D=JEb4FuPxmptLLZ1Y_qTjWt09wKDqJwFeg2ug-EPD88Q&paises%5BidToUpdate%5D=6
```

Now I need to get each `paises[pais]` and I'm doing as follow:

```
foreach($request->get('paises')['pais'] as $pais)
{
    echo $pais . "-";
}
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/html/project.dev/src/AppBundle/Controller/RPNI/DistribuidorController.php
>   line 67

Also I tried this other way:

```
foreach($request->get('paises') as $pais)
{
    echo $pais . "-";
}
```

But I get this output:

```
8-JEb4FuPxmptLLZ1Y_qTjWt09wKDqJwFeg2ug-EPD88Q-6-
```

Which makes me think that only the latest `paises[pais]` was taken. So what I'm doing wrong? What is the right way to get each value in order to execute actions on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paises[pais]` is the same variable, so it will only take the last value. You're just overwriting the value and the last one sticks. You would need to make the name of the element `paises[pais][]` so it creates an array of those inputs. Then this loop will work.

```
foreach($request->get('paises')['pais'] as $pais)
{
    echo $pais . "-";
}
```

Comment: You're right, I get confused around add this to the form field `->add('pais', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle:Pais', 'property' => 'nombre', 'mapped' => FALSE, 'expanded' => FALSE, 'multiple' => TRUE))` and that `multiple`is which takes care of add the needed extra array level `[]`, thanks